# Which tool is "standard" when it comes to the presenting slides?

Tags: soft-question, software

Maybe this question belongs to some other place such as Academia SE, but I am interested in the specific case of the field of mathematics, so please forgive me.

I am writing my first research presentation in mathematics, and I will use a slide format such as Powerpoint or Google Slides. Right now I was trying to make use of some add-ons on Google Slides, and it works okay, and looking okay at least to me. But when I see some other mathematician's presentation, I can clearly see that they did not use TeX add-ons and share some standard style. So my questions are:

1. Is there any common method or tool or software to write a presentation (specifically, slides) in mathematics?
2. If there is, will it be recommended to follow "the standard"? Or people will not care if it is out of standard shape?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Most mathematicians use Beamer, which is a kind of extension to Latex that lets you make slides instead of the standard pdf documents.

Comment: @SamHopkins Oh yes! This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: as long as your type-setting looks professional (read, TeX/LaTeX), I don't think anyone will care which software you used; personally, I use Latexit to "drag and drop" equations into Keynote.